# search on multiple fields in couchbase spring data where all fields are not passed

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I need to write filtering method based on county/status/symbol.

my repository query looks like this

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE `platform`='FXSERVICE' " +
            "AND `deleted`=false "+
            "AND `country` like $country "+
            "AND `symbol` like $symbol "+
            "AND `state` like  $state "+
            "AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    Stream<TradeOrderDO> findByCountry(@Param("country") String country, @Param("symbol") String symbol, @Param("state")  String state);
```

and calling the api like this

```
String country = "INDIA";
String symbol = "INR";
String state = "MANUAL";
tradeOrderRepository.findByCountry(country, symbol, state)
```

Now I pass all the values (county/symbol/state) it works fine.

But if want to filter with only state and ignore county and symbol

```
String country = "%%";
String symbol = "%%";
String state = "MANUAL";
tradeOrderRepository.findByCountry(country, symbol, state)
```

Query does not work. It does not return any value.
In query editor of couchbase , '%%' wild card works but not working for repository query.
How do I write the query for this type of filtering.

Comment: Passing in a string of "%%" as a param means that it will be escaped, so I suspect that's why it's working in the query workbench but not in the code. Have you tried something like `"and country = '%' || $country || '%'"`?

Comment: @MatthewGroves There  are few documents which does not have country field. Query is returning zero result. any idea how to handle this scenario

Comment: you can use `MISSING` maybe to qualify? something like `(country IS NOT MISSING AND country LIKE '%' || $country || '%')`

Comment: You may also want to explore the Full Text Search (FTS) engine in Couchbase, since it may be more suited to this kind of search: https://www.couchbase.com/products/full-text-search

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE `platform`='FXSERVICE' " +
            "AND `deleted`=false "+
            "AND `country` like '%' || $country || '%' "+
            "AND `symbol` like '%' || $symbol || '%' "+
            "AND `state` like  '%' || $state || '%' "+
            "AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    Stream<TradeOrderDO> findByCountry(@Param("country") String country, @Param("symbol") String symbol, @Param("state")  String state);
```

With this query it works.